# Which site can I ask the economic post?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask about the economic crisis & foreign expansion relationship. On which site can I ask these types of questions?

Comment: Consider looking at [the list of sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) when you wonder where a question might be posted on Stack Exchange.

Comment: What is "foreign expansion" (in this context)?

Comment: like germany occupy europe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Economics Beta](https://economics.stackexchange.com/) site seems like the appropriate place for such questions.